# Load models in Keras

Tags: keras, model, auc

I use this code to load a model in Keras using a customer metric (AUC) but this does not work. Could you help me to solve that problem ?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                        train_dir,
                        target_size=(32, 32),
                        batch_size=10,
                        class_mode='binary')
val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                        val_dir, 
                        target_size=(32, 32),
                        batch_size=10,
                        class_mode='binary')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=1405,
                              epochs=1,
                              validation_data=val_generator,
                              validation_steps=10)

model.save('baseline.h5')

model1 = models.load_model('baseline.h5')
```

I got a ValueError

```
ValueError: Unknown metric function: {'class_name': 'AUC', 'config': {'name': 'auc', 'dtype': 'float32', 'num_thresholds': 200, 'curve': 'ROC', 'summation_method': 'interpolation', 'thresholds': [0.005025125628140704, 0.010050251256281407, 0.01507537688442211, 0.020100502512562814
```

EDIT : I add the imports. I have heard about the argument 'customer_objects' in the load_model method. But I tried : 'custom_object'={'auc':keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')}

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from keras import models
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: Please add the imports to this example, they are important

Comment: Yes, I added the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't compile the model:

```py
model1 = models.load_model('baseline.h5', compile=False)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC()])
```

Comment: By setting `compile=False` you are getting rid of information about loss, optimizers, and other things, that were defined in `compile` function. If you think, the answer is correct, please mark it